# Yocto Weston Chromium Kiosk Mode Disable Shortcuts and Function keys

Tags: linux, chromium

I am trying to find a way to disable the F1, Ctrl+T, an Ctrl+N functions for a kiosk I am creating with chromium. I am using Weston as the compositor. I am also building Yocto with bitbake. As far as I have seen there is no option when building with Bitbake or at run time to disable these shortcuts in chrome.

The kiosk I am working is intended to immeaditely boot to chrome and open a predifined site, but I do not want the user to be able to break out of it at all. The user should be locked to this page and not be able to escape.

Xmodmap is not available to rebind keys since the OS is not X11 based.

I have also tried using programs such as Keyd and Kmonad; however, these require the uinput kernel module which is not installed in my Yocto build.

The furthest I was able to get was disabling Left and Right Control Keys using XKB Symbols, adding the option to evdev, then setting the options in the weston.ini file. There are currently two problems with this. One is that I can't for some reason disable the function keys with this. Secondly, I am having build problems when trying to overwrite the weston.ini and the evdev file in bitbake.

So that leads me to a few questions which I am hoping to get some help/expertise on:

- Is there a way to manually install the uinput kernel module? If so, how?
- Is there a reason why the function keys cannot be rebound like other keys in XKB?
- Are there any other options I have to disable these keys or shortcuts? Or is the a broader change I should make to my kiosk to more easily achieve my intended goal of a single web app?

Comment: One small pointer I can give you is for the system controll keys (SC keys according to /usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h, keys like poweroff / hibernate, etc.), you can inhibit system reaction to these by disabling them in systemd-logind configuration (assuming you are systemd based), see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/logind.conf.html

For everything else: did you find a solution? I am at the same point currently.